# Warning: UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread

Tags: iphone, multithreading

In my iPhone app I need to connect to a web server as this can take some time I'm using threads like this:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(sendStuff) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

- (void)sendStuff {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    //Need to get the string from the textField to send to server
    NSString *myString = self.textField.text;

    //Do some stuff here, connect to web server etc..

    [pool release];
}
```

On the row where I use self.textField I get a warning in console saying:
void _WebThreadLockFromAnyThread(bool), 0x5d306b0: Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread.

How can I use the textField without getting this error?

Comment: To help you we would need to know, why you are detaching a thread (What takes so long to do), which UI information you need and which UI information you want to update.

Comment: Hi! I updated the question. I need to connect to web server and I need to use the text from the textField to send to server.

Comment: You should accept Graham Lee or tonklon's answer. You should pull the search text before you spawn the thread and pass it as an argument to the selector.

Answer (score 12):

It depends a little bit on what you want to do with the textField. If reading the value is the only thing, you can do:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(sendStuff) toTarget:self withObject:self.textField.text];

- (void)sendStuff:(NSString*)myString {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    //Do someting with myString
    [pool release];
}
```

If you want to change a value on the textField you could:

```
[self.textField performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:@"new Text"];
```

Answer (score 11):

Perform any selectors that handle UI updates on the main thread. You can do this with the NSObject method [`-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1414900-performselectoronmainthread?language=occ)

Answer (score 3):

Why not:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(sendStuff:) toTarget: self withObject: self.textField.text];
```

?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed unsafe behaviour. The MainThread is the only one that should interface the UI. Have your thread return for instance a string to the mainthread and have a method there update the UI. You can do for instance do this by passing a selector to the other thread method, and then have the other thread call the selector on the mainthread.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

will work