# Is addsubview on iOS thread safe?

Tags: ios, thread-safety, gdc

I'm using Apple's  [Page Control](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Listings/Classes_iPhone_PhoneContentController_m.html) sample and my UIScrollview isn't smooth when scrolling. I'm thinking about using GCD. I believe that all my code is thread safe, except for my last line which is [self.scrollView addSubview:myView].

The docs that I read all mentions that UIKit is not thread safe, but the examples given are always related to setting values such as self.myLabel.text = @"some text".

Is addSubview thread safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All interface manipulation should be done in main thread! In other case you'll probably would gain painful headache.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. Y

Answer (score 1):

[You should call all UIKit methods on the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201761/warning-uikit-should-not-be-called-from-a-secondary-thread), this includes `-[UIView addSubview:]`.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that this would not be thread-safe.  To my knowledge, the only thing you can do with UIKit that is thread-safe is creating instances of UIImage (but not adding them to a view).