# GCD, queues affecting child UIViewcontrollers, reentrant

Tags: ios, uiview, grand-central-dispatch, uivewcontroller

Assume we have one `UIViewController`, call it A, in the `viewDidLoad` of that VC we add to it two `UIViewControllers`( B,C ). now to make the UI smooth in the `viewDidLoad` of A we do some GCD work

```
  dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myqueue", NULL);
  dispatch_async(queue, ^{
  // Create webviews, do some setup here, etc etc
  // Perform on main thread/queue
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  // this always has to happen on the main thread
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
   });
 });
```

So the `ParentViewController` is somewhat better in UI rendenring.

My question is: Is this enough GCD work? or should I do the same thing in thew `viewDidLoad` of the child `viewcontrollers`? just because I created those child VC's on a background thread does that mean I need not do any GCD wokr on them? I am trying to make my UI as responsive as possible, but not clutter the code. I guess another way of wording this would be are GCD threads reentrant? is there a concept of reentrancy in iOS?

Comment: Are you actually having a performance problem that you have investigated, and identified view setups as the cause of?

Comment: Well I was able to boost some performance by implementing this code. I justs wanted to know whether the affects of this trickle down the hieraqrcy of viewcontrollers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that adding a subview is a significant performance hit. Also, playing with views (or UIKit in general) should be done on the main UI thread. As far as I know it's considered bad practice to do such things in the background.

Try to save GCD/Async stuff to processor-intensive work or tasks of unknown durations such as downloading something from the internet.

Source and more info: [Warning: UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201761/warning-uikit-should-not-be-called-from-a-secondary-thread)

Comment: well adding a generic view is not, but maybe adding a uiwebview that loads some pdf file, or some complex view is.